# iptables on debian blocking git pull, http api requests etc

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am using IPTables on an API server to block all incoming traffic except for SSH, HTTP and HTTPS. I need to have full access on the loopback interface to run `beanstalkd` amongst other things, and need outgoing http, https and SSH access for API calls to other services, as well as pulling from github.

I created the rules as follows:

```
iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

`iptables -L` outputs:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Despite this, `git pull` can't find the server, pinging google doesn't work and mailgun won't send. Running `iptables -F` fixes these problems, and I cannot afford to have a firewall that just prevents my application from working completely...

How can I achieve what I'm trying to above?

Comment: Generally, post iptables rules using `-S`, not `-L`, as the "friendly" format omits a lot of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite obvious when you think about it:

- Pinging Google doesn't work because you do not have a rule that allows incoming ICMP replies.
- Things can't "find the server" because you do not have a rule that allows DNS replies.
- Mailgun can't talk SMTP because you do not have a rule that allows SMTP packets – the TCP SYN goes out, but the corresponding SYN/ACK gets dropped.

The general solution here is to use netfilter's connection tracking aka "conntrack" to make a rule that allows all packets that correspond to active connections:

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

*(Older documentation might have `-m state`; this is deprecated.)*

---

And of course,

```
-A INPUT -4 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -6 -p icmp6 -j ACCEPT
```

because *why would you block that*

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: (and just as a side note: I'm using Mailgun via API calls, not SMTP)